# Find the last value in a range that does not have an equivalent negative value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data that has a list of codes, with each code having multiple dated entries against them (example of one code sample).

```
CODE       DATE                    DATA
120160     07-Jun-18               2.8
120160     07-Jun-18               -2.8
120160     06-Jun-18               4.0
120160     06-Jun-18               -4.0
120160     05-Jun-18               2.5
120160     04-Jun-18               1.2
120160     04-Jun-18               2.2
```

In the data set there are hundreds of different codes.

Codes often have minor modifications made to their data at the end of their lifetime - hence why on the 7th June, there is a +2.8 and a -2.8. Codes can also have more than one +ve value on a date. What I need to do is return the last date with a sum of more than 0.

I can make a unique list of codes. I started with an index/match/max function to find the last date in the range but I am not sure how to return the last date that has a sum of more than 0 (i.e. ignoring any date that has a +ve value and then a equal -ve value).

In my example above, it would return 05-Jun-18.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Aggregate to return the largest date that meets that criteria:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:B8/(SUMIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,E2,B2:B8,B2:B8)<>0),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I was gona recommend VBA route.. :)

Comment: Amazing thanks. This works really well on a sample of the date but made excel crash on 94000 lines of data. Any tips for a simpler formula?